# Generate a special period image

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, image-processing

Construct a program or function that takes input in form of

```
<width>, <height>, <color1>, <color2>
```

and generates an output such that first row alternates between pixels of color  `<color1>` and `<color2>` with a period of `<height>`. For each row that follows, the period shall be `<height> - <row number>`. Note that `<color1>` always begins the row.

#### Sample Output

Input `120, 6, #000000, #FFFF00`:

[image: Sample Output]

Input `80, 50, #000000, #FFFF00`:

[image: Sample Output 2]

(Sample output has been scaled for clarity)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid entry in bytes wins.

Comment: Is that a fractal? Does it have a fractal dimension?

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 177 bytes

```js
g=
(w,h,f,b)=>`<svg${s=` width=${w} height=`+h}><rect${s} fill=${b} />`+[...Array(h)].map((_,i)=>`<line stroke=${f} stroke-dasharray=${h-i} x1=0 y1=${i} x2=${w} y2=${i} />`).join``
```

```html
Width: <input id=w value=80 type=number min=1><br>Height: <input id=h value=50 type=number min=1><br>Foreground: <input id=f value=#000000><br>Background: <input id=b value=#FFFF00><br><input type=button value=Go! onclick=o.innerHTML=g(+w.value,+h.value,f.value,b.value)><div id=o>
```

Outputs an HTML5-compatibile SVG image.

Answer (score 5):

## Tcl/Tk, 143

## <s>147</s> <s>150</s> <s>151</s>

```
proc P {w h b c} {set p [image c photo -w $w -h $h]
time {incr y
set x 0
time {$p p -t $x $y [expr {[incr x]/($h-$y+1)%2?$c:$b}]} $w} $h
set p}
```

Returns the image which can be tested, by putting it on a `canvas` widget, writing on a file, may be on the clipboard, etc.

## Code for testing

```
set w 960
set h 540
pack [canvas .c -w $w -he $h -highlightt 0]
.c cr image 0 0 -image [P $w $h #00ffff #ffbf32] -anchor nw
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>129</s></sub> 122 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1:D1]` and outputs to the range `[A2].Resize([B1],[A1])`

```vb
Cells.RowHeight=48:For Each r in[Offset(A2,,,B1,A1)]:r.Interior.Color=IIf((r.Column-1)\([B1]-R.Row+2)Mod 2,[D1],[C1]):Next
```

### Far More Interesting Version, 160 bytes

<sub>Presented w/ newlines in place of `:` characters for readability</sub>

In this version the snippet `[Let(r,Offset(A1,,,B1,A1),If(IsOdd((Column(r)-1)/(B1-Row(r)+2)),C1,D1))]`
alone is able to calculate the array of values, and all other code is used to output this array as colors to the range `[Offset(A1,,,B1,A1)]`.

```vb
Cells.RowHeight=48
[Offset(A2,,,B1,A1)]=[Let(r,Offset(A2,,,B1,A1),If(IsOdd((Column(r)-1)/(B1-Row(r)+2)),C1,D1))]
For Each r In Cells
r.Interior.Color=r
r="
Next
```

Perhaps this approach my prove fruitful for further improvement?

### Output

Output for input `160, 90, 0xBDD7EE, 0xDDEBF7`:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 52 bytes

```
Image@Table[If[Mod[j,2i]>i,#4,#3],{i,-#2,-1},{j,#}]&
```

Sample input:

```
Image@Table[If[Mod[j,2i]>i,#4,#3],{i,-#2,-1},{j,#}]&[120,6,Black,Yellow]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>155</s> 143 bytes

Prints a Portable PixMap (.ppm) to stdout.

```c
x,y,z;f(w,h,r,g,b,R,G,B){for(y=~0,printf("P3 %d %d 255",w,h);y++<~-h;)for(x=~0;x++<~-w;)z=(x/(h-y)%2),printf("\n%d %d %d ",z?R:r,z?G:g,z?B:b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc5BC4IwFAfwc30KEYKtnjgnUrgi6NI1OndJbZtQGkNwGvXVbXNQwuMdfvz/b8sDkefDoKGDnnHUggQFAjI4wxEO@MVrhbrdh8BTlVXDkX@KvUVhhyaJDyaPWbdabT@BZNiGtQkzPUrLcL9DOkQy6PCC4t@NS@VOmPGh359TZfYxFWYf0gyz9/C4lhUyr6P5LFy2ZdFIz1uGHtEJAUvyVgrZOIqpIYt5fa9VpEa8FvAnMRIhE8pGKvi0Sl2VR/8cddX1bUKuGm3m9qNf)

#### Output

- Input: `80, 50, #ad00df, #f17e18`

[image]
*(Image converted and resized.)*

Comment: What is the advantage of writing `~0` instead of  `-1` ?

Comment: @sergiol It looks cooler. And -- theoretically -- if you need a variable containing only `1`s, `~0` would be more portable than `-1`.

Comment: this image killed my eyes when I was scrolling past it. +1

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>34</s> <s>32</s> 29 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)

```
XJx:P"1Hh@Y"1Jyn/XkX"J:)]viYG
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=XJx%3AP%221Hh%40Y%221Jyn%2FXkX%22J%3A%29%5DviYG&inputs=80%0A50%0A%5B0%2C+0%2C+0%3B+255%2C+255%2C+0%5D&version=20.4.1)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 321 + 42 = 363 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;import java.awt.image.*;
(w,h,a,b)->{BufferedImage i=new BufferedImage(w,h,1);Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)i.getGraphics();g.setColor(new Color(a));g.fillRect(0,0,w,h);g.setColor(new Color(b));for(int j=h;j>0;g.drawLine(0,h-j,w,h-j--))g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1,0,0,1,new float[]{j},j));javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(i,"png",new java.io.File("a"));}
```

Outputs to a PNG file named `a` (no extension).

Surrounding code used to run the lambda: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJNS8QwED1vf8Wwp1TS0hUEoawHPyqCIuhRPMx203ZitylptAtLf/uaaSuigofw5uO9N@mkGj8wMq1q9PbteKRda6wD7Ysx9i4@SYPfJdphqbjRvm9qyiGvsevgAamBQ7CgxilbYK4ggwN8GNoC5rlqnfAd6CUwVBPgBJsQXGVN38HNnplkmhSGIFjMAzqHzsPotfNjxLOz1JQvr2jL7q@Wb7HIoIC1R9HLSqLchNEFlxeX70WhrNre8UcArRvVw4/aKFiFKZNvLbYV5d3pNZRr8Z2FFJfKfeViIpdxp9yVqY0VbDpFGH41C6rrJ5U7kchE@hn/iDazqPAx70evq1RfJGkZby3299Qob1JFmm0iHUVhyOzJy6/GvKnR7BI7yud8JXnsSnK9qA26l9eDHqSeJ/Hb7qeHJROPe7h7jHtLTgmSy7Ypl6N0/Ac8I6NaiSUuJ/ngD2MRzy99nkg48yfZZ1mSZNkUccz8IRiOx08)

### Ungolfed

```java
(w,h,a,b)->{
    BufferedImage i=new BufferedImage(w,h,1);
    Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)i.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(a));
    g.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    g.setColor(new Color(b));
    for(int j=h;j>0;g.drawLine(0,h-j,w,h-j--))
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1,0,0,1,new float[]{j},j));
    javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(i,"png",new java.io.File("a"));
}
```

### Result

Inputs: `80, 50, 0xFF00FF, 0xFFFF00`.

[image: example output]

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 83 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
..¹Cbe¹"εģνļ▲I-℮eīÆoHι⅛ļJd⁾)⁶f°┌²‘→e∫Ab∫Ƨ01a∙H∑bmWrcwιFHea-¹"S⁸▒Μ¬NrηA¤Y_⅓ļpPboā⁵‘→
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=Li4lQjlDYmUlQjklMjIldTIxNUQldTIwMzJtJXUyMjE5eUIldTIyMkJuJXUyMTVDeCUzQjAlMjQldTAxNkIldTAzQkQldTAzQjQlNUIldTIyMTklRjclQkQldTI1NUEldTIyMUVpJTA5QSVCOSV1MjAxOCV1MjE5MmUldTIyMkJBYiV1MjIyQiV1MDFBNzAxYSV1MjIxOUgldTIyMTFibVdyY3cldTAzQjlGSGVhLSVCOSUyMlMldTIwNzgldTI1OTIldTAzOUMlQUNOciV1MDNCN0ElQTRZXyV1MjE1MyV1MDEzQ3BQYm8ldTAxMDEldTIwNzUldTIwMTgldTIxOTI_,inputs=NDI3ODE5MDA4MCUwQTQyOTQ5NjcwNDAlMEExMjAlMEE2)

SOGL was made in Processing.. So I took advantage of that using `→` - execute as JavaScript. Could easily be many bytes less (at least 30) if SOGL had *anything* made for graphics.

Uncompressed strings:

```
..¹Cbe¹"__processing0.hidden=0;cp.size(ŗ,ŗ)”→e∫Ab∫Ƨ01a∙H∑bmWrcwιFHea-¹"cp.stroke(ŗ);cp.point(ŗ,ŗ)”→
```

Explanation:

```
..¹C       save the first 2 inputs as an array on variable C
be¹        save next input - width - on B, next input - height - on E, and wrap both in an array
"__processing0.hidden=0;cp.size(ŗ,ŗ)”→   
           execute "__processing0.hidden=0;cp.size(ŗ,ŗ)" as JavaScript - show the canvas and set the size to the corresponding items in the array

e∫A        repeat height times, saving 1-indexed counter on A
  b∫       repeat width times, pushing 1-indexed counter
    Ƨ01    push "01"
    a∙     multiply vertically A times             - ["01", "01", "01",...]
    H      rotate anticlockwise                    - ["000...","111..."]
    ∑      join together                           - "000..111.."
    bm     mold to the length of width             - "00011100011100"
    W      get the counterth letter of that string - "1"
    r      convert to number                       - 1
    cw     get that item from the variable C
    ι      remove the array from the stack
    FH     push current loops counter minus 1
    ea-    push e-a - height-outerLoopsCounter
    ¹      wrap the 3 items in an array - [itemInC (color), counter-1 (x position), height-outerLoopsCounter (y position)]
    
    "cp.stroke(ŗ);cp.point(ŗ,ŗ)”→ 
           execute "cp.stroke(ŗ);cp.point(ŗ,ŗ)" as JavaScript, replacing ŗ with the corresponding item from the array
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 84 bytes

```
DEF C W,H,C,D
FOR J=1TO H
FOR I=0TO W-1N=1AND I/J
GPSET I,H-J,C*!N+D*N
NEXT
NEXT
END
```

The color of a pixel at `(x,height-y)` is `[color1,color2][x/y & 1]`

Comment: hm, the specification asks you to input a color.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>123</s> 101 bytes

```python
w,h,c,C=input()
print'P3',w,h,255
for i in range(h):
 for j in range(w):print`[c,C][j/(h-i)%2]`[1:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v1wnQydZx9k2M6@gtERDk6ugKDOvRD3AWF0HJGNkasqVll@kkKmQmadQlJiXnqqRoWnFpQASy0KIlWtagfUlRAONio3O0tfI0M3UVDWKTYg2tNI1jP3/X8PCQEfBFIg1DCoMgBSC1ASLpaWBeBASKKYJAA)

Prints a .ppm to output as in Jonathan's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143598/38592).

Comment: Looks similar to my C answer... [105 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v1wnQydZx9k2M6@gtERDk6ugKDOvRD3AWF0HJGNkasqVll@kkKmQmadQlJiXnqqRoWnFpQASy0KIlWtaVdlm6Wtk6GZqqhpZg81IiAYaGxtdFZsQbWilaxj7/7@GhYGOgikQaxhUGAApBKkJFktLA/EgJFBMEwA) if you change your color input format (as the question does not rigorously define the color format).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks :)
Yeah, I got inspired by your answer when looking for a way to output the image.

Comment: Just out of curiosity; which program do you use to open your .ppm file?

Comment: `'%d '*3%` is shorter than `'%d %d %d'%`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech [This](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~smarz1/pgmview/) works, or I've used GIMP

Comment: Why then did you move from 101 bytes to 104 bytes?

Comment: I got confused by the [docs](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html). I'll change it back to 101

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) + HTML5, 138 bytes

```js
(w,h,a,b)=>{with(c.width=w,c.getContext`2d`)for(c.height=y=h;~--y;)for(x=w;~--x;)fillStyle=x/(h-y)%2<1?a:b,fillRect(x,y,1,1)}
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```

```js
f=
(w,h,a,b)=>{with(c.width=w,c.getContext`2d`)for(c.height=y=h;~--y;)for(x=w;~--x;)fillStyle=x/(h-y)%2<1?a:b,fillRect(x,y,1,1)}
```

```css
#c{display:block
```

```html
<input id=w value=80>
<input id=h value=50>
<input id=a value=#000>
<input id=b value=#FF0>
<input value=go type=button onclick=f(w.value,h.value,a.value,b.value)>
<canvas id=c>
```

The function outputs by operating on the `<canvas id=c>`.

Starting from the bottom right of the canvas, the nested `for` loop iterates to the left and up, and checks the condition `x/(h-y)%2<1` for the pixel at `x,y`. If the condition is `true`, it colors that pixel with `color1`, else `color2`.